# removing whitespace from tracking number in database

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Using Magento 1.7.0.2

Our data entry process in the past has entered tracking info with spaces (eg: xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx) which has caused tracking for customers to fail because of the whitespaces.

As opposed to changing each tracking number manually I wanted to change the function that calls the number to remove the whitespaces (tracking works properly when there are no whitespaces).

I believe I have traced it to this function:

```
public function getNumber()
{
    return $this->getData('track_number');
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is from Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want to remove the space character you may use str_replace

```
$track_number = str_replace(' ', '', $track_number);
```

to remove all possible whitespaces use regex

```
$track_number = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $track_number);
```

You may also consider to just clean up those spaces from database. This query would do the job:

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_shipment_track` SET `track_number` = REPLACE(`track_number`, ' ', '');
```

Comment: Your suggestion of the database query worked simply and very well. Thanks!